# Links wont work in div with JavaScript close element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am Playing around with
http://codepen.io/ettrics/pen/Jdjdzp
But because of the

```
var closers = $qsa('.modal__close'); // an element used to close the modal
```

If you put a link inside the container it wont work with left click but does with right click -> open link in new tab.

Is there anyway to keep the close element but also make it so links work?

Comment: There's not enough code posted **here** to answer

Comment: What's wrong really? modals working properly, and there is no link inside modals.

Comment: I'm trying to put links inside the modal and when I do the links don't work.

Comment: Perhaps you could show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your problem

Comment: I can tell you the issue is the click event on the `.modal__bg` divs - it's swallowing any click event without due care and attention - probably because modal's don't traditionally have links that navigate away from the current page (convention, not a rule)